# Is there any way to bring smooth corrective modifier effect to unity?

Tags: rigging, export, weight-painting, unity

Is there any way to bring a rigged model with smooth corrective modifier effect to unity?

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the modifier to make its effects part of the mesh data.

[image]

Comment: oh now I'm thinking the rigging complicates this a lot, but I'll wait for feedback